# Django admin inline with custom queryset

Tags: django

I've got two models:

```
class Parent:
   ...

class Child:
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

In the model admin of the **Parent** I want to show an inline of the **Child** with a custom queryset, not only the ones related to the parent through the fk field.

I've tried:

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Child
   def get_queryset(self, request):
      return Child.objects.filter(<my custom filter>)

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [ChildInline]
```

But still the only children shown in the inline are the ones that fullfill both filters: related to the parent by the FK + my custom filter.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

I've seen now is the BaseInlineFormSet who is filtering the queryset I compose to keep only childs related to the parent, any idea how to avoid this?

```
django/forms/models.py

class BaseInlineFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    ...
    if self.instance.pk is not None:
       qs = queryset.filter(**{self.fk.name: self.instance})
    ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The old answer doesn't work anymore for current Django 2.2 or 3 because self.queryset get ignored

Current solution is to override the `get_queryset`:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class ChildInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ChildInlineFormSet, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(<custom query filters>)

class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    formset = ChildInlineFormSet
    extra = 0
```

Comment: How to reference parent object in `<custom query filters>`?

Comment: @EugZol you can reference to this answer on how to get parent object https://stackoverflow.com/a/43617169/11225821

Answer (score 15):

You have to override `__init__()` method of BaseInlineFormSet and update queryset there.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class ChildInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Now we need to make a queryset to each field of each form inline
        self.queryset = Child.objects.filter(<my custom filter>)
```

Then initialise formset attribute with **ChildInlineFormSet**

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    formset = ChildInlineFormSet
    extra = 0
```

Comment: Didn´t work. What I need is to ignore the superclass filter that uses the FK field.

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check and let me know if this worked?

Comment: What if we need access to the request or user object?

Comment: It does not work in Django 2.2.5. self.queryset is ignored. I always get all data

Comment: @hipertracker please use .get_queryset() instead of .queryset