# django admin inline fields options filtered based on main form field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have the following Models:

```
class Organizations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)

class Postcodes(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organizations,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    postcode = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()

class Agent(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organizations,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class AgentPostcodes(models.Model):
    agent= models.ForeignKey(Agent,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    postcode = models.ForeignKey(Postcodes,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

and admin.py is

```
class AgentPostcodesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AgentPostcodes

class AgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['organization','name']
    inlines = [AgentPostcodesInline]
```

How can I have the inline form fields filtered based on organization for postcodes related to that organization only.
Currently it shows postcodes for all organizations even not related to the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Override `TabularInline`([`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options)) `get_queryset` method similar to what is described in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset):

```
ModelAdmin.get_queryset(request)
```

> The get_queryset method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all
> model instances that can be edited by the admin site. One use case for
> overriding this method is to show objects owned by the logged-in user:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: Additionally this might help you further
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150088/django-access-the-parent-instance-from-the-inline-model-admin

Comment: Inline how to get the organization from main form? that is the question in short. get_form and form.base_field["organization"], selected value I can not get and using formfield_for_foreignkey() can have again queryset for the field not the single value. :(