# InlineModelAdmin.get_queryset() how to access parent object?

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django admin, I have an Inline, and I would like to filter the list of rows by the parent object.

I can override `get_queryset(request)` in my Inline, but I don't have access to the parent object.

This snippet is from Django's options.py:

```
    def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix):
        formset_params = {
            "instance": obj,
            "prefix": prefix,
            "queryset": inline.get_queryset(request),
        }
```

This would by immediately solved, if Django would provide `obj` as an argument to `inline.get_queryset()`.

How to implement a `get_queryset()` of an `InlineModelAdmin` instance, so that it has access to `obj`?

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        ???? how to get the parent object?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code are the implementation of how inline admin instance are instantiate in Django

```
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    inline_instances = []
    for inline_class in self.get_inlines(request, obj):
        inline = inline_class(self.model, self.admin_site)
        if request:
            if not (
                inline.has_view_or_change_permission(request, obj)
                or inline.has_add_permission(request, obj)
                or inline.has_delete_permission(request, obj)
            ):
                continue
            if not inline.has_add_permission(request, obj):
                inline.max_num = 0
        inline_instances.append(inline)
    
    return inline_instances
```

as you can see there is no obj passed to the inline_class so normally you can't access the parent instance.

Override this function in your parent model's admin class and use assigned attribute 'parent_obj' in your get_queryset method will make it work.

```
# parent admin class

def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    inline_instances = super().get_inline_instances(request, obj)
    for inline_instance in inline_instances:
        inline_instance.parent_obj = obj
    return inline_instances

# inline admin class

def get_queryset(self, request):
    self.parent_obj  # you can now access your parent obj
```

Answer (score 1):

I reffered to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41065115/17524955 and provided one change:

- replace args to kwargs which contain an object_id

  ```
   def get_parent_obj_from_request(self, request):
       resolved = resolve(request.path_info)
       if resolved.kwargs.get('object_id'):
           return self.parent_model.objects.get(pk=resolved.kwargs['object_id'])
       return None

   def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super().get_queryset(request)
       parent_obj = self.get_parent_obj_from_request(request)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I found this dirty hack. In my case `Event` is the parent-model:

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # dirty hack to get the parent-object (event).
        # Please fix it and tell me,
        # if you know a better way to get it.
        event_id = request.path_info.split('/')[-2]
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If i see those questions, i understand, how many people works with django and completely don't understand it.

## First.

> In the Django admin, I have an `Inline`,
> and I would like to filter the list of rows by the parent object.

You don't need to do it in `Inline` object. `Inline` is only the **helper**, who organize creation of `InlineFormSet`.

And on the first lines of `__init__` of your `InlineFormSet` - it get `parent_object` and made "filter the list of rows by the parent object" for inline.queryset. (django.forms.models.py, row 904 in Django 4.07)

It means, if you want to filter `inline.queryset` by `parent_id` before, it has not any reason to do it twice.

## Second.

Please avoid loops. for example - get_inline_instances is good to set parent_object. But not in form of @pakawinz answer. You can do it better:

```
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    return ((instance, setattr(instance, 'parent_object', obj))[0] for instance in super().get_inline_instances(request, obj))
```

And you can do it much better:

```
def get_inlines(self, request, obj):
    """Hook for specifying custom inlines."""
    return (type(inline.__name__, (inline,) {'parent_object': obj}) for inline in super().get_inlines(request, obj))
```

Second example add `parent_object` like an attribute to `inline_class`. it give you possibility to get `parent_object` in `classmethods` too.

## Third

Your question already has the best possibility to give an inline a parent_object to use it in queryset

```
def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix):
    inline.parent_obj = obj 
    return super().get_formset_kwargs(request, obj, inline, prefix)
```

## Four

@NackiE23 tells you a better way to get `parent_object`.
Please don't use `path.split()`, this is not works for `add_view` in `ModelAdmin`. in your case:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    ... # your staff
    resolved = resolve(request.path_info) # this is a better way to get it.
    if resolved.kwargs.get('object_id'):
        event = resolved.func.__self__.get_object(request, resolved.kwargs.get('object_id'), to_field=None)  # please check if you don't need to_field
    else:
        event = resolved.func.__self__.model()
```

Please check, how work your solution not only for change_view, also for add_view too.

## Last

I work only with `django.admin.contrib` more than 7 years. You can find my Talks about django.admin.contrib on **PyCon RU 2021**, **PyCon DE 2022**, **DjangoCon EU 2022** and, later, on **DjangoCon US 2022**.

With my experience I think, probably, you do something unnecessary in your code. But i am not sure, therefore i write you some solutions above.

Comment: In above text I see comments to other answers. Just out of curiosity, why don't you leave the comments directly on the particular answer?

Comment: On First is the answer on your question. On second or third or four i write a code. In comment you can not use code-style. And ewery time i change some functionality.